# AWS - Tab Schema Conversion don't show up after creating a Migration Project

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-dms

I'm trying to convert a MariaDB do MySQL using Schema Conversion within DMS.
But after creating the Migration Project I don't see a Schema Conversion tab.

I was following the tutorial mentioned below.
At 10:22 there is a Schema Conversion Tab but I'm not able to see it.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u7yKzYpbiLk